# How to display post in custom file not in archive file?

Tags: categories, redirect, archives, wp-redirect

I create file content-expertises.php and display my category list. Now, When I click one my category name, it is redirect in category.php file not my custom created file like category-expertise.php.

My current path is:

```
  http://hostname/expertises/project-reviews/
```

When I click my category name it is redirect in:

```
  http://hostname/categories/category-name/
```

But, not redirect in my custom created (file is clone of archive file):

```
 http://hostname/expertise/category-name/
```

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend looking at the template hierarchy diagram, it will save you a lot of time in questions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file named content-expertises.php or category-expertises.php?

WP will use the first template file it finds in your theme directory from the following list:

```
category-slug.php
category-ID.php
category.php
archive.php
index.php
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: My current file named content-expertises.php and I wont to redirect in category-expertises.php by category link.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: simply, I wont to redirect in my created custom file not in archive file.

Comment: I get my solution as :<taxonomy>-texonomyname.php thanks #jdm2112 & #Tom J Nowel.